# sCommand not found

Tags: screen, touchscreen, sudo

I am trying to install a waveshare LCD touch screen on a Raspberry Pi running the OctoPi (Raspbian based) OS.

Following the [Waveshare tutorial](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD#How_to_apply_the_RPi_LCD_in_a_custom_Raspbian_system_mirror_image.3F):

I have downloaded and extracted the drivers and moved them onto the /home/pi folder using WinSCP. Now when I navigate to /home/pi/LCD-show and try to run-

**sudo ./LCD5-show**

I get the response-

**sudo: LCD5-show: command not found**

Is there another way to run the command? I know that the file name is correct and I am in the correct folder. I have checked the LCD5-show file and I don't see anything blatantly wrong with it so I'm assuming I am messing up the syntax somewhere.

Comment: Check the permissions on the file. They should include the eXecutable bit. To make sure the file is executable, you can type 'sudo chmod 755 ./LCD5-show` - this will make the file executable for its owner, the owners group and everybody else. If you want to make it explicitly only executable by the owner, do `sudo chmod 744` which takes away the group and everybody executable rights.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the command is in the folder by using `ls ~/LCD-show` if it is there, then you may need to edit the file permissions via `chmod` enter the command: `sudo chmod +x ~/LCD-show/LCD5-show`. If that doesn't work, make sure you are typing the name of the command correctly, and that `LCD5-show` is actually the name.